# how can I deal with null errors in axios and vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Axios and Vuejs

I am receiving data from the api,
but some items are null,
and I get a message on the console,
how can I deal with these errors

[image]

[image]

I tried to make a filter but it didn't work.

link: [App](https://github.com/eduardo239/tv-maze-app)

Comment: can u add code where you got this error ? instead of giving link of your project if u can add the particular part of code where you are getting error so people will look at it otherwise no one will give a look at your whole app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you could post some of your code from your Vue component, but there are many ways to deal with this. In general, you need to check for the value before displaying. Below are a couple of ways you could do this with Vue.

One way is using [v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html). If the network is not null, show the network

```
<div v-if="show.network">{{ show.network }}</div>
```

You could also use a [v-else](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-else) directive to display something else

```
<div v-if="show.network">{{ show.network }}</div>
<div v-else>network unavailable</div>
```

Another way is to use a [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) property.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>{{ network }}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            show: {
                network: null
            }
        }
    },
    computed: {
        network() {
            return ( this.show.network ) ? this.show.network : "not available";
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

The list goes on... As the developer, you will need to check the value to determine if it can be shown before displaying it.

Comment: The v-if worked but the computed I'm still learning, sorry for not posting the code, I'm new here

Answer (score 1):

From your template, you can use this code:

```html
<p><span>Network: </span>{{ result.show?.network?.name || '' }}</p>
```

All browsers dont support `?` so below will always works:

```html
<p><span>Network: </span>{{ result.show && result.show.network && result.show.network.name }}</p>
```

Comment: Might be worth noting support for this method. Not all browsers will support this (IE), and without the proper build modules in Vue, it won't be backwards compatible. Also, thanks for teaching me something new today :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Thanks, the second solution worked, but the first solution the vue didn't recognize the ?.

Comment: maybe the browser compatibility as Chris mentioned